# Search for string on each list item

Tags: string, list, erlang

I need to search in the `List` for the its item that have this string: `sp1_inicio.pbf`.

The list is in this format:

```
["X,sp1_inicio.pbf,2,AB5E","X,sp1_chile.pbf,3,4F46"]
```

The application name is the second element `sp1_inicio.pbf` and the version is the third element, `2`.

The application name is unique, no matter how big the list is, it won't repeat.

So based on the first string I need to search inside this list for the correct application and get its version number.

These data is returned from Riak, in the code bellow I'm showing only the method that I've created to deal with that situation.

Here is my code where I get the list and the file name (don't expect much, it's my first code):

```
get_application_version(LogicalNumber, Acronym, Object) ->
    {_, Where, Name, _, _, _, _} = Object,
    {ok, Client} = riak:local_client(),
    % Try to get the logical number from the bucket terminals
    case Client:get(<<"terminals">>, LogicalNumber) of
        % If the logical number is returned, its value goes to the Terminal Variable
        {ok, Terminal} ->
            % Returns the Terminal value, in this case it is a json: group: xxx and decode it
            {struct, TerminalValues} = mochijson2:decode(riak_object:get_value(Terminal)),
            % Use proplist to get the value of the decoded json key 'groups'
            % Here we already have the group ID of the current logical number in the variable GroupID
            GroupId = proplists:get_value(<<"group">>, TerminalValues),
            % Acronym with _
            Acronym_ = string:concat(binary_to_list(Acronym), "_"),
            % Group with acronym ex.: ab1_123
            GroupName = string:concat(Acronym_, binary_to_list(GroupId)),
            case Client:get(<<"groups">>, list_to_binary(GroupName)) of
                {ok, Group} ->
                    {struct, GroupValues} = mochijson2:decode(riak_object:get_value(Group)),
                    AppsList = proplists:get_value(<<"apps_list">>, GroupValues);
                    %%% Right here I have all the data required to make the list search
                    %%% The list is inside AppsList
                    %%% The application name is inside Name
                {error, notfound} ->
                    io:format("Group notfound")
            end;
        {error, notfound} ->
            io:format("Terminal notfound")
    end.
```

I don't know if creating a list with string is the best way of doing this or even if this is the fasted approach and that worries me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. I don't see `sp1_inicio.posxml` anywhere in your list. So please provide example of input and desired output if you willing to get answer. It will be also helpful if you provide more info where data comes from and what you would like to achieve.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil thanks a lot for your feedback, I'll improve the question right now and sorry for the typo.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil I have updated the question, if there is anything missing, please let me know =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for example code like this:

```
find_app(Name, AppsList) ->
    F = fun(X) ->
                case string:tokens(X, ",") of
                    [_, Name, Version|_] -> {ok, Version};
                    _ -> next
                end
        end,
    find_first(F, AppsList).

bin_find_app(Name, AppsList) ->
    F = fun(X) ->
                case binary:split(X, <<$,>>, [global]) of
                    [_, Name, Version|_] -> {ok, Version};
                    _ -> next
                end
        end,
    find_first(F, AppsList).

find_first(_, []) -> not_found;
find_first(F, [X|L]) ->
    case F(X) of
        next -> find_first(F, L);
        Result -> Result
    end.
```

Example of usage:

```
1> c(search_for).
{ok,search_for}
2> L = ["X,sp1_inicio.pbf,2,AB5E","X,sp1_chile.pbf,3,4F46"].
["X,sp1_inicio.pbf,2,AB5E","X,sp1_chile.pbf,3,4F46"]
3> Name = "sp1_inicio.pbf".
"sp1_inicio.pbf"
4> search_for:find_app(Name, L).
{ok,"2"}
5> search_for:bin_find_app(list_to_binary(Name), [list_to_binary(X) || X <- L]).
{ok,<<"2">>}
```

**Edit**: You can work with binary as well.